# How to solve the following system of equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

$2x^2-3xy+2y^2=2\frac{3}{4}\\x^2-4xy+y^2+\frac{1}{2}=0$

I tried all the methods that I know, but I could't isolate $x$ or $y$ to form one equation.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the equations in terms of $u = x^2 + y^2$ and $v = xy$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Multiply the second by $2$, substract the result from the first. So, $x^2$ is gone and you express $x$ as a function of $y$. Plug it into one of the equations to get one equation in $y$.

Comment: If you can look at my answer, it'd be a big help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply second equation by $2$,
$$2x^2-8xy+2y^2+1=0$$
Substract the first equation by the second,
$$2x^2-3xy+2y^2-\frac{11}{4}-(2x^2-8xy+2y^2+1)=0\\2x^2-3xy-2y^2-\frac{11}{4}-2x^2+8xy-2y^2-1=0\\5xy=\frac{15}{4}\\x=\frac{3}{4y}$$
Substitute $x=\frac{3}{4y}$ in the first equation,
$$2x^2-3xy+2y^2=\frac{11}{4}\\2(\frac{3}{4y})^2-3(\frac{3}{4y})y+2y^2-\frac{11}{4}=0\\\frac{9}{8y^2}+2y^2-5=0\\16y^4-40y^2+9=0$$Now use the quadratic Formula to solve $16y^4-40y^2+9=0$,$$y^2=\frac{-(-40)\pm\sqrt{(-40)^2-4.16.9}}{2.16}\\y^2=\frac{40\pm\sqrt{1600-4.16.9}}{2.16}\\y^2=\frac{40\pm\sqrt{16(100-4.9)}}{2.16}\\y^2=\frac{40\pm4\sqrt{64}}{2.16}=\frac{40\pm4.8}{2.16}=\frac{5\pm4}{4}\\y^2=\frac{5+4}{4}=\frac{9}{4}\Rightarrow y=\pm\frac{3}{2}\\or,~~y^2=\frac{5-4}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\Rightarrow y=\pm\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: $$2(\frac{3}{4y})^2-3(\frac{3}{4y})y+2y^2=\frac{11}{4}$$
$$2\frac{9}{16y^2}-\frac{9}{4}+2y^2=\frac{11}{4}$$
$$\frac{9}{8y^2}+2y^2=\frac{11}{4}+\frac{9}{4}$$
$$\frac{9}{8y^2}+2y^2=\frac{20}{4}$$
Then by multiplying it by $8y^2$ you get:
$$9+16y^4=40y^2 \Rightarrow 16y^4-40y^2+9=0$$

Now you can continue as you did before..

Comment: Thanks a lot Mary. I will correct the solution. :)

Comment: At the quadratic formula it is like that:
$$y^2=\frac{40 \pm \sqrt{1600-4 \cdot 16 \cdot 9}}{2 \cdot 16}$$
$$y^2=\frac{40 \pm \sqrt{16(100-4 \cdot 9)}}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 4}$$
$$y^2=\frac{40 \pm 4 \sqrt{100-36}}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 4}$$
$$y^2=\frac{10 \pm \sqrt{64}}{8}$$
$$y^2=\frac{10 \pm 8}{8}$$
$$y^2=\frac{18}{8}=\frac{9}{4} \Rightarrow y= \pm \frac{3}{2}$$
$$\text{Or } y^2=\frac{2}{8}=\frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow y= \pm \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you Mary. Seems like i'm making silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said in other answers, first solve for $xy$

$$2x^2-3xy+2y^2=\frac{11}4$$
$$-2x^2+8xy-2y^2=1$$
$$5xy=\frac{15}4$$
$$xy=\frac34$$

Now take the original second equation and manipulate it.

$$x^2-4xy+y^2+2xy=-\frac12+2(\frac34)$$
$$(x-y)^2=1$$
$$x-y=\pm1$$
$$x^2-4xy+y^2+6xy=-\frac12+6(\frac34)$$
$$(x+y)^2=4$$
$$x+y=\pm2$$

So there are 4 pairs of linear equations for 4 different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

By multiplying the second by $-2$ you get:
$$2x^2-3xy+2y^2=\frac{6}{4}$$
$$-2x^2+8xy-2y^2=1$$
Then adding them you get:
$$5xy=\frac{10}{4} \Rightarrow xy=\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{2y}$$

Substituting this in the second equation you get:
$$\frac{1}{4y^2}-2+y^2+\frac{1}{2}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{4y^2}+y^2=\frac{3}{2}$$

Multiplying this equation by $4y^2$ you get:
$$1+4y^4=6y^2 \Rightarrow 4y^4-6y^2+1=0$$

Let $u=y^2$:$$4u^2-6u+1=0$$
Then continue by solving this quadratic polynomial...

Comment: I believe the $2 \frac{3}{4}$ in the first equation for $x,y$ should be interpreted as a mixed fraction, not a product, so it equals $\frac{11}{4}$, not $\frac{6}{4}$ as you've assumed.

Comment: Thank you. @Mary Please look at my answer and tell me if it's correct wrong.